# Stacking fa-circle-o and other icons whilst maintaining vertical and horizontal alignment

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm attempting to stack two icons. My attempt looks awful, because the central icon isn't centred within the `fa-circle-o`.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-th-large fa-stack-1x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

Is there a nice way to resolve this within the stacking system provided by font awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't solve that using font-awesome classes, but you can do a very simple styling applying `margin-top: 1px`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-th-large fa-fw fa-stack-1x" style="margin-top: 1px"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-fw fa-stack-2x"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: This one seems to work a little better at different zoom levels, so accepted